# getting error in jump to next activity

Tags: android

```
Friends.java
Intent intent = new Intent(Friends.this,MyMapActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivityForResult(intent,0);
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".MyMapActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@androidtyle/Theme.NoTitleBar">
</activity>
```

ERROR:

```
04-30 11:38:53.165: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(822): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-30 11:38:53.165: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(822): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.bestdambikers.MyMapActivity
04-30 11:38:53.165: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(822): at com.bestdambikers.Friends$5.onClick(Friends.java:793)
04-30 11:38:53.165: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(822): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
04-30 11:38:53.165: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(822): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
04-30 11:38:53.165: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(822): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-30 11:38:53.165: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(822): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-30 11:38:53.165: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(822): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-30 11:38:53.165: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(822): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
04-30 11:38:53.165: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(822): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-30 11:38:53.165: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(822): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-30 11:38:53.165: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(822): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-30 11:38:53.165: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(822): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-30 11:38:53.165: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(822): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-30 11:38:53.165: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(822): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation
04-30 11:38:53.165: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(822): at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(Native Method)
04-30 11:38:53.165: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(822): at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:207)
04-30 11:38:53.165: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(822): at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:200)
04-30 11:38:53.165: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(822): at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
04-30 11:38:53.165: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(822): at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
04-30 11:38:53.165: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(822): ... 12 more
```

I don't know why i am getting this error. I have also tried startActivity(new Intent(Friend.this,MyMapActivity.class));
Even though i m getting this errors.

I have declared the class in the Manifestfile too.

Comment: I think the answer is already in your log. Have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 2):

In Manifest you have MyMapctivity and in code MYMapActivity...characters "y" and "Y" are different...=)

> Intent intent = new
>   Intent(Friends.this,MyMapActivity.class);

and

> activity
>   android:name=".MYMapActivity"

the name of class Different...Change everywhere  to MyMapActivity....

Comment: Ya,i know its case sensitive.I checked but the file name was correct.

Comment: 04-30 11:38:53.165: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(822): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.bestdambikers.MyMapActivity.  Maybe your class name is MYMapActivity instead of MyMapActivity

Answer (score 0):

add your activity in menifest..

```
<activity android:name="MapActivity" ></activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

clean the project, then recompile it.